# How to parse captured packet from socket in cpp?

Tags: c++, string, packet-capture, unsigned-char

I'm using RAW socket to capture udp packets. After capturing I want to parse the packet and see what's inside.

The input I get from the socket is an unsigned char* buffer and it's length. I tried to put the buffer into a string but I guess I did it wrong because when I checked the string it was empty.

Any advice?

Comment: The buffer is likely to contain `'\0'` values, how did you assign the `std::string` from the buffer? There's a version of the [`assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) function, that takes an explicit size to transfer.

Comment: After looking around, i tried: std::string s(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(buffer), buff_len);

Comment: I recently had a similar case, and decided to use a `std::array<uint8_t,PACKET_LENGTH>` to store the raw packet data. But I have all packets from that protocol, that have a fixed size, which is known in advance. Another suitable type would be `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use std::vector<uint8_t> in order to a get a string from the unsigned char* buffer?

Comment: You get an empty string when the original buffer length is 0. You can get an apparently empty string when your check for emptiness is incorrect.

Comment: [`vec.assign(std::begin(buffer),std::end(buffer));`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign), supposed the buffer is a locally declared fixed size array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to parse, but your have the buffer and it's length. So you can do everything you want with this memory. Look for pointer arithmetic. If you want to make an C-String out of the content, simply add an '\0' to the end of the memory block. But this assumes, that no other 0x00 are inside the buffer. So maybe you have to check that. Like  πάντα ῥεῖ said.

Steps:

1: receive UDP package

2: cast like:

```
unsigned char* buffer;
char* cString = (char*) buffer;
```

3: check casted cString if an '\0' occurred before buffer size was reached. If it does, then create a new char* pointer to the byte after the '\0', but be aware of the buffer size. Save the pointer in an vector.

I made an code example, but haven't checked if it is runnable!

```
char* firstPtr = (char*) buffer;
size_t indexer = 0;
std::vector<char*> pointerVec;
pointerVec.push_back(firstPtr);

while(indexer < bufferSize) {

    if(*(buffer + indexer) == '\0') {
        if(indexer + 1 < bufferSize) {
            char* cString = (char*) (buffer + indexer);
            pointerVec.push_back(cString);

        }
    }
} // end while
```

After that you should have the positions of the different strings saved with the pointers inside of the vector. Now you can handle them to an copy mechanism which takes every C-String pointer and saves it's content to one C-String or String.

Hope you searched for something like that, because you question was unclear.